# What is the impact of setVisibility changing Visible to Visible? Android

Tags: android

Sometimes I need to change my image's visibility from the java code and I don't want to check every time whether the status of visibility is equal of the value of I want to change to. Namely, an image is visible and I want to change into visible again. What is the cost of that function or is there any cost of that function?

Comment: no need to use the android studio tag for this question, you're not asking about the IDE itself

Comment: What do you mean by cost? and in what context you're asking about the impact? it about performance or time or anything else. Please be specific.

Comment: I meant performance, however, performance and time are somehow related, so I didn't mention. Thanks for the massage anyway. @Vijay

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a check at the beginning of the  method part of the View class so I would not bother to check myself:

```
/**
     * Set the visibility state of this view.
     *
     * @param visibility One of {@link #VISIBLE}, {@link #INVISIBLE}, or {@link #GONE}.
     * @attr ref android.R.styleable#View_visibility
     */
    @RemotableViewMethod
    public void setVisibility(@Visibility int visibility) {
        setFlags(visibility, VISIBILITY_MASK);
    }

 /**
     * Set flags controlling behavior of this view.
     *
     * @param flags Constant indicating the value which should be set
     * @param mask Constant indicating the bit range that should be changed
     */
    @UnsupportedAppUsage(maxTargetSdk = Build.VERSION_CODES.P, trackingBug = 115609023)
    void setFlags(int flags, int mask) {
        final boolean accessibilityEnabled =
                AccessibilityManager.getInstance(mContext).isEnabled();
        final boolean oldIncludeForAccessibility = accessibilityEnabled && includeForAccessibility();

        int old = mViewFlags;
        mViewFlags = (mViewFlags & ~mask) | (flags & mask);

        int changed = mViewFlags ^ old;
        if (changed == 0) {
            return;
        }
```